# Is it called a double stop if you play the same note on two different strings?

Tags: theory, guitar, technique, harmony, violin

As the title says. If you play a note simultaneously on two strings in the same octave, is it still considered a double stop?

Comment: Guitar or violin? I've never heard anybody use the term 'stop' when talking about guitar, only the violin family.

Comment: @Tetsujin Doesn't really matter. But even if it's very rare, they sometimes talk about it on guitar too.

Comment: On the guitar it would be called a two-note chord.

Comment: Depends. If a music teacher is talking to his pupil about how to finger the passage, then its a double stop. If it's a critic discussing the harmonic texture of the bar, then it isn't, it's just an irrelevant technical detail.

Comment: @Tetsujin - any stringed instrument can evoke the term 'stop'. It is used with reference to guitar.

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg - some violently disagree! Partially as a '2 note chord' can't be named. Intervals can. Like a 'power chord' is P5.

Comment: @Tim What do you mean with that a 2 note chord cannot be named? E5 is a perfect name for the E power chord.

Comment: @Tim Another - rather clumsy, but working - name is E no3

Comment: @klutt - so what do we call, for example, C and E? (As a 'chord').

Comment: @Tim Firstly, it's possible to come up with a name for anything. You just pick a name, and then state the definition. And a sensible name for C and E would be C no5. However, I do agree that it is a rather clumsy name, but not clumsier than Cmaj11b5 add(m2) add(m3)

Comment: @Tim And yes, the conventional name for naming chords is not good at all for two note chords. Just saying that it's possible. C and A can be named C6 no3 no5 :)

Comment: @klutt - hence as of now, chords really need three notes minimum?! (Not going to chat).

Comment: @Tim Some people say that, but there's a large disagreement. It makes some sense to have a word meaning "chord with at least 3 notes" but I think it's much more vital to have a name that includes chords with 2 notes. Since the word chord is widely used for 2-note chords, especially power chords, I'd say that those who want a special word not including those should invent a new word for it.

Comment: @klutt - the word 'chord' is only used widely for *one* 'chord' - the power chord. As far as I know, there are no other widely used two note chords. They don't (or can't) exist.

Comment: @Tim Ok sure. Other two chords rarely get names. But it still a large disagreement that 3 notes should be a hard requirement for a chord. And even if I agree to that definition, it's still abundantly clear what a 2-note chord means. In the same way, a toy car is not a real car, but that does not make it meaningless to describe something as a toy car. I can understand why you don't want to call it just a "chord", but arguing against the use of the specific phrase "2-note chord" seems extremely pointless.

Answer (score 15):

Called a double stop as two (sometimes 3) strings are being held down/played simultaneously. Usually the notes are part of a harmony, but can be the same as each other.

In that case, I'd expect them to be called *unison double stops*.

Comment: What would be the point of doing this on a unison?  Is it just louder?  Could you not get the same effect more easily by just bowing one string harder?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - no, the effect just is not the same. Simple. On guitar, violin, etc. Consider one person singing a note compared with two singing that same note.

Answer (score 12):

Yes.

The word "[stop](https://books.google.com/books?id=gDsfAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA101)" refers to where the string is stopped, meaning where it ends. So, first think of the nut as the stop for an open string. When you finger the strings on the neck you are making a new stop. And, of course, double stop just means you are doing that on two strings.

It doesn't matter what the interval is. The point is how many strings you are changing by "stopping" them with your fingers.